# Editable objects shown as on every layer - how did that happen?

Tags: layers

There are a number of objects in a file I've been working on for a long time that have this setup I don't understand. They show as being on all layers but they are one object. They can be edited, so they aren't objects linked from another file.

[image: example object showing how layer menu shows it is on all layers]

I must have done this months ago but I can't recall how or why, and I'd like to change it. What is this setup and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: An object can belong to any arbitrary number of layers at the same time. Press M to bring up the *Move to Layer* menu to change them. Holding Shift while clicking the layer buttons adds to multiple layers

Comment: @batFINGER yep. How do you find these things? This wasn't imported, i think maybe i intentionally did it for some editing reason and then forgot to undo it, and then forgot how i even did it. :P

Comment: Have wondered re exactly the same question, as I have come across this too, and am dead sure I never bothered to set all layers to true deliberately.  Could be a bit of "fail-safe" code in an addon  to make sure ob is on whatever layer, or some key combo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any object can be on any amount of layers at the same time by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> when selecting the layers in the popup that appears after pressing <kbd>M</kbd> in *Object Mode*.

Just press <kbd>M</kbd> again to move the object to the desired layer.